# Content-Type for file export with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, powershell, content-type

I have a problem. I try to force the charset(ISO-8859-1) to download a file with this code :

```
$response = new Response($data);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.ps1');
$response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->headers->set('Expires', 0);
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
 
return $response;
```

but I still get a file in utf-8...
I looked in the profiler, I see the good charset but nothing works.

I feel that it still keeps the default charset of the application :s

Do you have any idea where it can come from?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're actually downloading the file it up to the external application that opens the file to honor the encoding (and not override it).

I think that `charset` only matters when you're outputing the content to the browser

Comment: i have find ! The problem was in the charset data...

    $response = new Response(utf8_decode($data));

Now, It's work !

thx :)